# I'm trying to compare two columns on different sheets and if a match then return the results from another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In a work book I have 2 sheets (sheet1 & sheet2)
both sheets have a list of serial numbers in column C

I need to compare and if they match, return the results from Sheet1!G of that result
(this formula would be on sheet 2) so if Sheet1!C2 matches Sheet2!C8 return Sheet1!G2

Someone else on this forum had suggested the following formula for a similar issue, but I'm having trouble understanding and making if fit my needs.
=IF(ISNA(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,A:A,0))),"",INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,A:A,0)))

Also, I'm doing this on Excel online 365.

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: In `Sheet2`, put this formula in the first cell and then drag down: `=INDEX(Sheet1!$G:$G,MATCH($C1,Sheet1!$C:$C,0))` or if you want something other than `#N/A`, you can use `IFERROR` as well: `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$G:$G,MATCH($C3,Sheet1!$C:$C,0)), 0)` Change the last `0` to whatever result you want returned if there is no match.

Comment: Thank you! 
though, for some reason, it's returning just zeros. I have at least 1 row I know should return a match and it also is just 0.

Comment: For example
sheet1!C36 matches sheet2!C8 and I need it to return the data in sheet1!G36 to sheet2

Comment: I would YouTube some videos on how to index-match. Make sure the values are exactly the same. My formula should work.

Comment: Got it, thank you! I didn't quite understand what you meant by using the =IFERROR, but using that made it work!